# Task.async_stream elixir returning strange output

Tags: asynchronous, elixir, phoenix-framework

Using Task.async_stream just fine in my uploading many files to S3.

Attempting to use it in a download_many function that takes a keyword list of urls and ids. When I run the download_many function in an iex session, it returns the following output:

```
iex(1)> Karma.S3.download_many(1)
    #Function<1.112846234/2 in Task.build_stream/3>
    #Function<1.112846234/2 in Task.build_stream/3>
```

Here is the function:

```
def download_many(_urls) do
    urls = [
      “5”: “https://engine-image-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/engine-image-uploads/d4a9f8adb58b4e0b83c47e8f3b21d421-fillable.pdf“,
      “3”: “https://engine-image-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/engine-image-uploads/ccd6d66cb4304b369a025efe3b26e68b-fillable.pdf”
    ]

   ops = [max_concurrency: System.schedulers_online() * 3, timeout: 20000]

   tasks = Task.async_stream(urls, &download_with_id/1, ops)
    |> Enum.to_list()
    IO.inspect tasks
  end

 def download_with_id({id, url}) do
    file_destination = System.cwd() <> “/tmp/altered_document_” <> Atom.to_string(id) <> “.pdf”
    download(url, file_destination)
    |> Tuple.insert_at(2, id)
  end
```

And a link to the file: https://github.com/karmaradio/karma/blob/async-download_many/lib/S3.ex#L58

I don’t understand the output: `#Function<1.112846234/2 in Task.build_stream/3>`

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the stream function generated by `Task.async_stream/3` but `|> Enum.to_list` should run the stream and return a list.. not sure why it's returning the stream for this code.

Comment: (For example, `Task.async_stream([1, 2, 3], &(&1 + 1))` returns `#Function<1.40752444/2 in Task.build_stream/3>`, but adding `|> Enum.to_list` returns a list.) Are you _sure_ the code you pasted here is the one you ran?

Comment: Yeah you were right! I was running a previous version of the code, sorry!